Use type inference for function to return only specific value?
Below is what I tried, and it is working okay, but I want to utilize infer in typescript to make this function return a specific value:
function one() {
        return "one";
 }

 
interface IConfig = {
  isDebugMode: () => 'prod' | 'development',
};

function one() : IConfig['isDebugMode'] {
   return process.env.mode;
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is Infer? Why do you have a need for a particular way of doing it? Perhaps you're looking for function one() { return "one" as const; }? But note nothing called Infer is in that. Please [edit] to either clarify or remove the reference to Infer. Does as const meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (or find a suitable duplicate to link to). If not, what am I missing?

I want to use infer R ? R : never like to make function to return specific value? is it possible?

something like this type inference :
type SettingReturnType<T> = T extends () => infer R ? R : never;


interface Config {
  mode:  () => 'dev' | 'prod';
}


function getApiUrl(): SettingReturnType<Config['mode']> {
  return 'prod';
}

